# How "fsutil transaction" works and how can transactions be enabled?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, fsutil

ntfs transactions appeared with [Windows Vista](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/volkerw/archive/2006/06/09/624540.aspx) and this features were plugged in **fsutil** command. From fsutil help message:

```
---- TRANSACTION Commands Supported ----

commit          Commit a specified transaction
fileinfo        Display transaction information for a specific file
list            Display currently running transactions
query           Display information on a specified transaction
rollback        Rollback a specified transaction
```

But the *start* switch is not presented. How can enable transactions?How files in `C:\Windows\System32\config\TxR` are related to the transactions.

Comment: Check [Fsutil resource](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621564.aspx), in particular `fsutil resource start`

Comment: fsutil resource /?

Comment: Using Transactional NTFS is discouraged by Microsoft. That being said, it is not something for end-users, but rather [an API for programmers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa964931(v=vs.85).aspx#transacted_functions).